# I am trying to pick out all the rows with '1's in a particular cell for a large range, is there a more efficient way to do this?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a beginner and have written something that looks at a huge table and picks up all the rows that contains '1'.

It has about 2000 rows and am relatively slow to go through them all, is there a more efficient way to evaluate the data?

```
function lookFor1(){
  var trendster = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('trendster');
  var pusher = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('pusher');
  var lastRow = trendster.getLastRow();
  for(k=0; k<=lastRow; k++){
   var j= trendster.getRange(3+k, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
    if(j==1){
      var range = pusher.getRange("C6:C26").getValues();
      var rangeLast = range.filter(String).length;
      var pusherLastRow = pusher.getLastRow();
      trendster.getRange(3+k, 1, 1, 8).copyTo(pusher.getRange(rangeLast+6,3,1,8), {contentsOnly:true});
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QWuAdbQY8rFsGHrQlEWYYYQT-Z3zmxjacaca-sIpcPc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You can use the filter function, or an If statement using concatenate and regexextract - if you share a sample spreadsheet I can put a sample formula in there for you

Comment: just to clarify - does this inclue a 1 in any string of numbers also? or just where any row/cell contains only a value of 1 or -1?

Comment: Just on Column B within the trendster tab.

Comment: if you can please choose mine as the "accepted answer" thanks :) you can add any comments if you have any other questions too

Comment: Sorry, just realised that the solution doesn't work for numeric figures that came from formulas.

Hence still unsolved, perhaps an efficient script will work?

Comment: what do you mean numeric figures - it should still work - do you have an example?

Comment: Did you already try wrapping your numeric figure in double quotes? It will treat it as a string that way.

Comment: It works fine if I manually enter 1 in the target cell (i.e. on column B/trendster), however if the cell is using a formula to get the 1, it won't work.

I'll try to modify the formula to clean up the numeric value in the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter based on the number 1 and pull in the full rows you can enter this formula:

```
=filter(trendster!A1:AJ,trendster!B1:B=1)
```

Comment: Thanks - solved again, needed to clean the if statement to make it numeric rather than a text.